# React Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Actually, I am having an error in React while I am trying to import "New.js" components in "App.js"
Here is App.js code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import New from './components/New/New';

function App() {
  const [familiar, setFamiliar] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>IsFamiliar: {familiar.toString()}</h2>
      <button onClick={()=> setFamiliar(!familiar)}>Toggle</button>
      <New></New>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and here is the New.js components code:

```
import React from 'react';

const New = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>I am a component</h1>
        </div>
    );
};

export default New;
```

And, **I am getting this error**:

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: `Import New from './components/New/New';` you sure this path is accurate? Usually what that error points to is importing incorrectly, e.g, importing a named export as default or vice versa.

Comment: Yeah! I have checked it! There is no issue with this path.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-taussig-lxl1e?file=/src/App.js works fine for me with my directory structure, which is imitating your pathing. Does your directory look exactly like this?

Comment: Thank you So much! I have copied your code from sandbox and pasted to the VScode. And it's worked! But, I didn't get what was my wrong!  Did you find any issue with my code?

Comment: No. I pasted yours into sandbox and arranged the files according to your import statements. :)